# How to share current app's APK (or of other installed apps) apk file in my flutter app (sending app itself)?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk, share

Many libraries available like `share_plus: ^6.3.0` to share files, text, images but I want to share my apk itself to others.

Can anybody assist me to how to achive this in my `flutter app` ?

Comment: Note that an app can consist of multiple APK files depending how it was installed (most apps from PlayStore are delivered as multiple APK files).

Comment: how can I find and how can I share ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sharing the file to install, I recommend sharing a link to the appstore or playstore so that the recipient can install it. Installation files for normal devices are usually a threat, and the system will refuse to install it.

Comment: I have a offline app it's size 250 mb. Our sales representatives share our apk to the users. Some of the users has no internet. That time we need to share the apk from app itself

Comment: You can check out [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/shareapks):.

Comment: Yah, This is what I need @Sang Pham. Thank you so much 